# Not recognizing if condition in python

Tags: python

My code is not being read at the second if statement (this only works if S1 is longer than S2)... I am trying to create a new sentence by alternating other two sentences. If there is a longer one, then that longer piece should go at the end of the new sentence.

```
s1 = 'aaaaaaaaa'
s2 = 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
s3 = ''
final = ''

x = len(max(s1,s2))

if len(s1) > x:
    s3  = s1[x:]        

if len(s2) > x:
s3 = s2 [x: ]


s1 = s1[:x]    
s2 = s2 [:x]


for i in range(len(s1)):    
    final += s1[i] + s2[i]    

final += s3
print final
```

Comment: You are using `>`. `len(s1)`and `len(s2)` can only be smaller or equal to their max.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `if` statements for whether the length of one of your strings is longer than the length of the max of both strings... evidently this will never evaluate to true.